# can't import import datetime in script

Tags: python, datetime, python-import

I cannot import datetime from a python script, but I can from the terminal command line.

```
1)import datetime
2)From datetime import datetime

month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")
print month
```

These lines of code work when entered one by one into the command line
Any ideas?

I'm running 2.7 on mac

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: File "/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.py", line 4, in <module>
    month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")

Comment: you named that test module datetime.py?! that cannot work, obviously.

Comment: @ch3ka It is not obvious at all why it can't work, unless you know the module system rather well and know one relatively obscure detail (that the current directory is searched).

Comment: well, if it wasn't obvious, this incident might be a great motivation to learn about the module system ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

1. you named your file `datetime.py` for testing
2. then you wrote `import datetime` inside it, because that's the module you want to try out

What happens when you run the file, is that:

3. Python first looks into your local directory for a module called `datetime`
4. Since Python only finds your original file, it makes an empty module file called `datetime.pyc`, because it expects you to build upon it

Luckily, the nice people at StackOverflow made you aware of this naming error, and you renamed your `datetime.py` file to something else. But confusingly you **still** get errors and the frustration slowly builds...

## Solution:

1. Always make sure that your filenames aren't equal to any Python module you want to import
2. If you still forget, then make sure to delete or rename *both* the local `.py` script *and* the local `.pyc` file. This should fix your problem. :)

The reason this is such a common error, is that people like testing stuff when programming. And when they do, the natural inclination of most people is to make a script with the same name as the thing they want to test. However that's one of the first *gotchas* most Python developers run into. If the cool people that designed Python read Donald Norman before making their system, this would never be a problem. But as it is, we just have to adjust to how the Python module system works before naming our files. Note: There are still reasons for the Python module system working this way, however that doesn't preclude it from being confusing to beginners.

Comment: ugh.. this, in particular, is what was biting me.. thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You named your *script* `datetime.py`, located at `/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.py`. This is being imported instead of the standard library module, because the directory of the main script is the first place Python looks for imports.

You cannot give your scripts the same name as a module you are trying to import. Rename your script. Make sure you also delete the bytecode cache at `/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.pyc`.

Comment: I renamed it thescript.py I got the same error.  Also, I got the error on another script called NHLWeb.py.  I just used the name datetime.py to show the error from another code.

Comment: File "/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/thescript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: @JosephLee: Look at that traceback. `/Users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/datetime.pyc` probably still exists,

Comment: Also, the folder python does not hold python libraries, only the scripts that I write.... I don't know if that helps

Comment: @JosephLee: Doesn't matter; modules can be scripts and scripts can be modules. They are all python files.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line is overwriting what python understands the word 'datetime' to mean in later code.  You should either use

```
import datetime                 # the complete module
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime   # one part of the main module
month = datetime.now().strftime("%B")
```

Answer (score 1):

while saving the scripts make sure you give it different name (other than ***date time***) and save it in c:/Python34/Scripts; i' m sure this will work then.